# How to Insert auto increment primary key into database table

Tags: java, sql, insert, primary-key, auto-increment

I have am inserting `CSV` file that is chosen using a `JFileChooser`.I get an error when importing, It display that the primary key `IS NULL`. It is auto-increment(I used and SQL command). What's strange is that the exact same insert code is working for a different table in the same database. Here's the code I have so far:

**JAVA CODE**

```
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
             if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                Scanner sin = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(file.getName())));
                while (sin.hasNext()) {

                    String[] line = sin.nextLine().split(",");
                    String name = line[0];
                    String surname = line[1];
                    int age = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
                    String gender = line[3];
                    String shoeSize = line[4];

                    Studentstbl st = new Studentstbl();
                    st.setAge(age);
                    st.setDonationStatus("N");
                    st.setFirstName(name);
                    st.setGender(gender);
                    st.setShoeSize(shoeSize);
                    st.setSurname(surname);

                        yritpatPUEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                        yritpatPUEntityManager.persist(st);
                        yritpatPUEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();
                        studentstblList.clear();
                        studentstblList.addAll(studentstblQuery.getResultList());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanel1, "A problem occured when         accessing the file "+file.getAbsolutePath(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jPanel1, "Cancelled by user", "Error",         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

**SQL**

```
    create table studentstbl (
    student_id int not null primary key
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
      (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    school_id int not null,
    first_name varchar(60) not null,
    surname varchar(60) not null,
    age int not null,
    gender varchar(1) not null,
    shoe_size int not null,
    donation_status varchar(1) not null)
```

**And**

```
    ALTER TABLE STUDENTSTBL
    ADD CONSTRAINT SCHOOL_ID FOREIGN KEY (SCHOOL_ID)
    REFERENCES SCHOOLSTBL
    (SCHOOL_ID)
```

**CSV**

```
    aname,asname,2,M,1
    bname,bsname,3,F,1
    cname,csname,4,F,2
    dname,dsname,5,F,3
    ename,esname,7,M,3
    fname,fsname,6,M,3
    gname,gsname,8,F,4
    hname,hsname,10,M,4
    iname,isname,9,M,4
    jname,jsname,14,F,7
    kname,ksname,12,F,6
    lname,lsname,13,F,6
    mname,msname,3,F,1
    nname,nsname,2,M,1
    oname,osname,15,F,6
    pname,psname,15,M,6
    qname,qsname,12,M,4
    rname,rsname,8,M,3
    sname,ssname,7,M,3
    tname,tsname,6,F,3
    uname,usname,5,F,2
    vname,vsname,14,M,6
    wname,wsname,12,M,6
    xname,xsname,6,F,2
    yname,ysname,8,M,2
    zname,zsname,7,M,2
```

Comment: Where is the code of your Studentstbl entity (which has an awful name, BTW. What's wrong with `Student`?)? Also, why do you start a new transaction for each and every line of the file?

Comment: I know, our school has a standard naming convention for testing purposes. Rather just go with it until I'm out

Comment: "why do you start a new transaction for each and every line of the file?" - I'm a student, still learning about this stuff. Is there a more effective way of doing it?

Comment: Yes: unless the file is really huge (read: millions of lines), a single transaction would be faster. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it in school today! I had hard coded a .get statement in the Studentstbl which fixed one of my other errors and caused this one. Deleting the entity, list and query and importing them again worked perfectly.